# Java Web Service - Has it to be in a new project?

Tags: java, web-services

As you can see, I'm really starting learning about Web Services and, in all examples I've seen, a new Web Project is created to implement the Web Service.

In my case, I already have a Web Application implemented and I need a WS to an Android app for this application. So, my question is: can I create the WS in this project or do I have to make a new project for that?

Any help will be apreciated, thanks.

Comment: There's no reason a service endpoint can't live within an existing web app. Whether or not it *should* just depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create the WS in this project or do I have to make a new project for that?

It depends on your design. Any web application can be the producer of the web services, so yes, you can use your current web application to host the services. But, there will be more requests to your application since there are new clients apart from internet browsers, so if your application is prepared to handle lots of requests, then do it. IMO it should be a different web application since they have different purposes, even if they use the same business services and data access layers, so if your main web application is undeployed for maintainability purposes, then your web application that hosts the services can be still up and running smoothly.